# NoClassDefFoundError on Android

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I want to create a path variable in my Android project, but everytime I get a NoClassDefFoundError.

```
test = test + ".turns"; //This is a simple String
List<String> turnlist = new ArrayList<String>();
Path testfile = (Path) Paths.get(test);
```

Logcat:

```
05-13 19:08:51.996: E/AndroidRuntime(23437): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1108
05-13 19:08:51.996: E/AndroidRuntime(23437): Process: com.example.voicerecorder, PID: 23437
05-13 19:08:51.996: E/AndroidRuntime(23437): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.file.Paths
05-13 19:08:51.996: E/AndroidRuntime(23437): at com.example.voicerecorder.activities.RecordActivity$TestLoader.run(RecordActivity.java:201)
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!
I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!
I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!
I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!
I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!
I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!
I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!
I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!
I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!
I will never again put my desktop jre into my android classpath!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use `java.nio.file.Paths`, which [doesn't exist in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) as far as I can see. (Only some parts of the Java 7 API are supported.)

It's not clear what path you're looking for, or what you're going to do with the result, but consider using `File`.

Edit, now that we know a bit more: You should *not* put your desktop JRE jar files in the classpath for an Android project. That's just asking for trouble. Without doing that, you'd have correctly got a compile-time error.

Comment: yep, you are correct. this is why i've put my J-SE1.6 (JRE7) into my classpath. does this still not work? and thx for your suggestion with file ;)

Comment: No!  And here I was wondering how you managed to sneak that by the compiler to have it turn up at runtime.  Don't put non-Android jar's in your classpath!  This is not functionality you can use - you aren't even allowed to implement it yourself under that name, as the toolchain blocks you from using the java.* and javax.* namespaces.

Comment: @ZerO: No, you can't just put a desktop JRE into your classpath and expect it to work on Android. (Nor is it clear why you're referring to J-SE1.6 as JRE7...)

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I was wondering too, but didn't have enough Android experience to know that it would normally fail. (I expected it to, but...)

Answer (score 1):

`java.nio.file.Paths` is part of the J7 API. Whereas Android (I believe) is built on J6. So, as such you'll be unable to use such classes. The `File` class is more than capable usually :)